# Why does tf.train.batch add an extra dimension to output in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

In TensorFlow, say we have training data `xs` in numpy NHCW format. I want to sample batches from `xs` in Tensorflow, I did

```
xs = np.reshape(range(32), [4,2,2,2])    
tensor_list = [tf.convert_to_tensors(x) for x in xs]
#x_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensors(xs) # tried this version too
x_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(tensor_list, batch_size=3, capacity=50, min_after_dequeue=10)
```

Instead of sampling from `tensor_list`, this code returns a list whose length is the same of the number of data points (4 in this case), and each list element is a tensor where the first dimension is `batch_size` (3 in this case). Personally the intuitive outcome would be `x_batch` is a 4 dimensional tensor and the value of the first dimension is `batch_size`, and the contents are randomly sampled. Then each time we call `sess.run(x_batch)` we have a different batch.

Please let me know where I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't figured this out, but found a different solution as below.

```
xs = np.reshape(range(32), [4,2,2,2])    
x_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(xs)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_tensor)
dataset = dataset.batch(2)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
sess.run(iterator.initializer)

while True:
  try:
    next_element = iterator.get_next()
  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print("End of dataset")  # ==> "End of dataset"
```

Then this will output a random batch of size 2 each time `iterator.get_next()` is called.